# Uploading jar on multiple flink job managers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

So currently we are using flink 1.12 in HA mode on production. There are 3 job managers (1 leader and 2 standby). When I am uploading a jar on one of the job managers, somehow it is not reflected on other job managers. Is there any way where I can achieve a behaviour where uploading jar to a single job manager also gets reflected in other job managers in HA as well?

The problem that I am facing due to this is that when the jar is uploaded on let's say 'A' job manager, but when sending a job submit a request using uploaded jar on 'B' job manager, I get an error saying jar not found.

Answer (score 0):

On https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/ha/overview/ is mentioned `State persistence: Persisting state which is required for the successor to resume the job execution (JobGraphs, user code jars, completed checkpoints)`

That implies that Flink's HA service takes care of the JARs part too. Have you tried what happens if you shutdown the active JobManager?